# Plotting a datapoint with a custom axis labels and values in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axis, datapoint

If I want to plot a datapoint (a circle) on my graph I need to give it and x/y coordiante.
My y-axis has numbers but I formatted my x-axis to have custom names labels. These custom labels places with a distance of 100 pixels each with tickValues e.g. 100,200,300 etc.

```
        xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xScale)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickValues(createTickValuesArray(arr.length))
            .tickFormat(formatAxis);
```

createTickValuesArray just generates the array of numbers for me.

If I want to plot a datapoint do I need to give it a numeric value? Or can I use the label names from my x-axis somehow?

Comment: You need to pass in the same kind of data that you're passing to the scale in other places.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you mean? I don't quite understand :(

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you're passing some data to `xScale()`, e.g. `xScale(d)`. Whatever the format of the data you're passing there you need to pass in other circumstances as well.

Comment: Okay I will take a good look and keep that in mind, thank you